# css animation and angular :not able to successfully implement " ease in -ease out" animation for spilt page for angular project

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

i am working on the following code and want to slide the both sides while hovered over please look through . i am working with angular html typescript and css
while hovering the mouse on each side of the screen should ease out ease in but that is not working
following is the html

```
<div class="container">

    <!-- LEFT SIDE -->


    <div class="split left" id="upComing">
        <h1 id="uce">THE UPCOMING EVENT</h1>
        <table id="tableTimer">
            <tr id="timerValue">
                <td id="days">{{timer.days}}</td>
                <td id="hr">{{timer.hr}}</td>
                <td id="min">{{timer.min}}</td>
                <td id="sec">{{timer.sec}}</td>

            </tr>
            <tr id="timerSub">
                <td>Days</td>
                <td>Hours</td>
                <td>Minutes</td>
                <td>Seconds</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>


    <!-- RIGHT SIDE -->


    <div class="split right" id="nextFive">
        <h1 id="nfe">THE NEXT FIVE EVENTS</h1>
        <table>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

following is the css i have implemented

```
html,
body {
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: rgb(75, 149, 199);
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 20%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    white-space: nowrap;
}


/* HEADER */

#header {
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}


/* FOOTER */

#footer {
    background-color: rgb(75, 149, 199);
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}


/* UPCOMING EVENT DIV*/

#upComing {
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}


/* NEXT ELEMENT */

#nextFive {
    align-content: center;
}


/* TIMER  */

#tableTimer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 40%;
    height: 150px;
    width: 350px;
    align-content: center;
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
    background-image: url(image/timerBckgrnd1.jpg);
    transition-property: background-image;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    display: block;
}

#tableTimer:hover {
    background-image: url(image/timerBckgrnd2.jpg);
    transform: translateZ(500px);
}

#timerValue {
    align-content: center;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-stretch: expanded;
    color: rgb(79, 35, 110);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}


/* TIMER ELEMENT */

#timerSub {
    color: black;
    font-size: small;
    align-items: baseline;
    align-content: bottom;
    font-stretch: expanded;
    text-align: center;
}


/* HOVER */

.split {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.split.left {
    left: 0;
    background: url('image/upComingEvent.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.split.left:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.split.right {
    right: 0;
    background: url('image/rightBackgrnd.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.split.right:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


/* adding transition to left and right */

:root {
    --speed: 1000ms;
    --hover-width: 75%;
    --other-width: 25%;
}

.split.left,
.split.right,
.split.right:before,
.split.left:before {
    transition: var(--speed) all ease-in-out;
}


/* from TS  */

.hover-left .left {
    width: var(--hover-width);
}

.hover-left .right {
    width: var(--other-width);
}

.hover-left .right:before {
    z-index: 2;
}

.hover-right .right {
    width: var(--hover-width);
}

.hover-right .left {
    width: var(--other-width);
}

.hover-right .left:before {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

following is the ts code , the function i have implemented

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '[app-landing]',
  templateUrl: './landing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landing.component.css']
})
export class LandingComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //this.countDown();
    this.slidLeftRight();
  }



// HOVER LEFT RIGHT

slidLeftRight(){
  var left,right,container;
left = document.querySelector('.left');
right = document.querySelector('.right');
container = document.querySelector('.container');

left.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    container.classList.add("hover-left");
});

left.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    container.classList.remove("hover-left");
});

right.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    container.classList.add("hover-right");
});

right.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    container.classList.remove("hover-right");
});
}

}
```

Comment: Any reason you're using Angular for this animation? You can do this with simple CSS.